# pass dynamic array of pointers to C function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I want to store each line of the file in an 2D array, and anthor array pointing each line (so I can identify each line), I need to pass this pointers array to a function so I can manipulate my lines, I d'ont know how to do that

I have this code to read and store in the arrays

```
char ligne[MAX];
//open end test the file
FILE* fichier = fopen("csp.txt","r");
if(fichier == NULL){
    printf("can't open the file \n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
//the first line in the file contain number of other lines
fgets(ligne, sizeof(ligne), fichier);
int nbrTaille = strtol(ligne, NULL, 10);

//array of pointers
char (*tab)[nbrTaille] = malloc(nbrTaille * sizeof(ligne));
int i = 0;

//tab array point each line
while(fgets(ligne, sizeof(ligne), fichier)){

    if(ligne == NULL) EXIT_FAILURE;

    strncpy(tab[i], ligne, strlen(ligne));  
    printf("line%d : %s\n", i, tab[i]);
    i++;
}
//call the funnction by passing array of pointers and the number of lines
allDiff(tab, nbrTaille);
```

the file I'm reading is

```
2
1 2
2 3
```

to receive the array by the function I tried this but it doesn't work

```
void allDiff(char** T, int taille)
```

Comment: Your comment `//array of pointers` is not accurate. That doesn't declare an array of pointers; it declares a pointer to an array. There is a difference. That decl should be `char (*tab)[MAX] = ...`. If you want a dynamic allocation for *each string* then all of that needs to change. And unrelated, `if(ligne == NULL) EXIT_FAILURE` is worthless. `ligne` is an automatic array and will thus *never* be `NULL`.

Comment: can I have this type of array (example: [1][1,2], [2][2,3]) without dynamic allocation (so that each line "i" contains as columns "j" my file lines [ i ][ j ]) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am always confused with the parenthesies and asterisks. The easier way is to declare a double pointer:

```
char ** tab;

//you need to take care of errors. I am not doing it for simplicity
//tab = {pointer1, pointer2, pointer3, ...., pointerN} total memory needed N * sizeof(pointer)
tab = malloc(lines* sizeof(tab)); //how many pointers you want
for(i = 0; i < lines; i++){
    tab[i] = malloc(MAX); //each string
}
```

In the end free the memory:

```
for(i = 0; i < lines; i++){
    free(tab[i]);
}
free(tab);
```

**EDIT** *complete code*

```
char ligne[MAX];
//open end test the file
FILE* fichier = fopen("csp.txt","r");
if(fichier == NULL){
    printf("can't open the file \n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
//the first line in the file contain number of other lines
fgets(ligne, sizeof(ligne), fichier);
int nbrTaille = strtol(ligne, NULL, 10);

//array of pointers
//char (*tab)[nbrTaille] = malloc(nbrTaille * sizeof(ligne));
int i = 0;
char **tab;

tab = malloc(nbrTaille * sizeof(tab)); //how many pointers you want
for(i = 0; i < nbrTaille; i++){
    //sizeof(ligne) is equal to MAX
    tab[i] = malloc(MAX); //each string
}

i = 0;

//tab array point each line
while(fgets(ligne, sizeof(ligne), fichier)){

    if(ligne == NULL) EXIT_FAILURE;

    strncpy(tab[i], ligne, strlen(ligne));  
    printf("line%d : %s\n", i, tab[i]);
    i++;
}
//call the funnction by passing array of pointers and the number of lines
allDiff(tab, nbrTaille);
```

Comment: `sizeof(int)` is wrong, and will invoke UB on any platform where `int` and `char*` are not the same size. Use `sizeof *tab` instead.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes. I forgot that pointer size is different from int.

Comment: I'm filling my table by reading lines file, I can't fill it like that it's not sizeof(int) but sizeof(line)

Comment: @devhicham I thought *nbrTaille* was the number of lines. Change it to lines instead.

Comment: how can I declare tab with sizeof(tab) in the malloc function, is that correct ? and what is MAX ? I cant fill it like this because I need to point it to the line when reading it, I don't understand what you mean

Comment: @devhicham *sizeof(tab)* is **not** how many pointers you have. It is the number of bytes a pointer occupies in memory.

Comment: I do know that, but if you take a look to my code, I use fgets() to fill it so I can't loop with for() inside it with a malloc()

Comment: @devhicham You do know the number of lines. From the first *fgets*. It is the *nbrTaille* variable. You use my code **before** the *while* loop.

Comment: the problem is in this line of code "strncpy(tab[i], ligne, strlen(ligne))" how can I allocate "tab[i] = malloc(MAX)" inside a strncpy() ?

Comment: ahaa! so you allocated all cells then you fill them in another loop, thnak you so much

Answer (score 1):

`void function(char tab[][MAXLEN], ...);`
This will do.

Comment: I can't cause the length is calculated inside the code, how to pass it ?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of readbility and sanity, typedef C function pointers before creating arrays or double pointers to them.

```
/* typedef the function pointer. An ftabptr points to a void function that
   takes a char * */
typedef void (*ftabptr)(char *p);


/* create an uninitalised list of twenty of them */
int N = 20;
ftabptr *pointerlist = malloc(N * sizeof(ftabptr));
```

However I don't think you really want to do this. You can write a
functioning program that does weird things with tables of function
pointers, but normally you use a language other than C if you
want to play that game (Lisp-like languages, etc). The high level 
language then often emits C as an intermediate step.